# Problemas de Adicionar pacote Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Estou iniciando alguns projetos com Xamarin Studio, estou tendo alguns problemas e ainda não consegui resolver sempre aparece esses 2 erros, olhei uma solução no stackoverflow.com, mas as soluções ali dadas não resolveram meu problema e como não encontrei nada igual, resolvi postar aqui.
Logo no inicio da minha aplicação, aparece

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
```

> The type or namespace name 'Xamarin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

```
public class App : Application
```

> The type or namespace name 'Application' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

A solução pra resolver isso é rotina tirada do stackoverflow.com

1. Select the project in the Solution tab
2. Select "Project" along the top menu
3. Select "Add Nuget Packages..."
4. Do a search for "Xamarin.forms"
5. Add "Xamarin.forms" to that project

O problema ao fazer isso é que ele não consegue adicionar o pacote do Xamarin, apresenta um outro problema:

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Forms 1.3.3.6323'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'portable-Profile78', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente a versão do pacote que você está tentando instalar é bem antiga, tente instalar a mais recente ([1.5.0.6447](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/)). Outro item é conferir se o profile que você selecionou no projeto ou o framework que você está usando é compatível:

- Qual versão do Xamarin Studio você está rodando?
- Qual versão do Xamarin.Android ou Xamarin.iOS este projeto está usando?
- Se é uma biblioteca PCL, qual profile esta biblioteca está  configurada para usar?

Se você está no Windows, garanta que você instalou o suporte para Portable Libraries e o Visual Studio 2013 ou superior ([veja como instalar aqui - link em inglês](http://lastexitcode.com/blog/2014/11/16/InstallingPortableClassLibrariesForXamarinStudio/)). Se precisou instalar o suporte e já tinha instalado o Xamarin antes, será preciso reinstalar o suporte.

Ademais o pacote referenciado dá suporte apenas para as seguintes plataformas: Portable .NET 4.5, Windows Phone Silverlight 8.0, Xamarin.Android, Xamarin.iOS e Xamarin.iOS (Clássico); não incluindo suporte para Silverlight 5.0. Você não pode ter outras plataformas ou versões maiores configuradas em seu projeto para poder usar este pacote.